# "index into the specified collection is out of bounds" inconsistent on different systems

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following code in an Excel workbook to paste the contents of a screenshot into a chart, then export the image as a PNG file.  This script executes as expected on one machine, but fails on another machine on line "With canvas.Shapes(1)" with the following error:

```
Error -2147024809: The index into the specified collection is out of bounds.
```

Both machines are Excel Version 14.0.7166.5000 (64-bit) running on Windows 7 Pro.  I cannot figure out why I would get an index error on one machine and not the other.

```
Set canvas = ws.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, GetSystemMetrics(DESKTOPX), GetSystemMetrics(DESKTOPY)).Chart
canvas.Paste

With canvas.Shapes(1)
    .ScaleWidth 100, msoTrue
    .ScaleHeight 100, msoTrue
End With

canvas.Export FileName, "png"

Do While ws.Shapes.Count > 0
    ws.Shapes(1).Delete
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a do while loop try using a For Each loop, this will only loop if the object exists and should prevent and discrepancies with indexing

```
For Each Shp in WS.Shapes
    Shp.Delete
Next Shp
```

See if that solves the problem.

-----------------NEW MESSAGE----------------

Set canvas = ws.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, GetSystemMetrics(DESKTOPX), GetSystemMetrics(DESKTOPY)).Chart
canvas.Paste <<<---- What is this pasting?

and the only reason canvas.Shapes(1) will return this error is when there are no shapes on this chart.... did you check when debugging?

--------------NEW MESSAGE--------------------

another note is what are you trying to scale? the chart or something on the chart? if i remember correctly the hierarchy goes like this
Sheet>Shapes>Charts>ChartObjects etc etc so if your trying to scale the chart you should be able to do it directly from your variable 'canvas' since this is a 'Chart Object' already.

Comment: The index issue actually occurs on the "With canvas.Shapes(1)" line, so this is before the delete action occurs.

Comment: A screenshot is being pasted from PrintScreen.

I used the scaling because some machines that will use this will have dual monitors, others have a single monitor.  This was the simplest method I tried that worked to capture and save at the original resolution.

I did step through the code.  When stepping through, it seems to work.  When executing in real time, it does fail with the same error.  I have tried adding three consecutive DeEvents commands.

Comment: Doing almost the exact same thing - trying to delete all shapes - but I'm getting the error message in my for each loop.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I notice that a debug check of the count size is giving over 100 objects in the array. When I switch to a simple for loop, the prog crashes when it gets to the final couple of objects. I could make it run by looping until count-1 but the next time it crashed. I changed to count-2 and it ran again but crashed the following time. It almost seems like there is a bug in the method that is returning the array size.